# Git ignore folders / sub-folders and csv / xlsx files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git folder with a mix of file types and folders.

```
git_folder 

  sample.py
  xyz.ipynb
  folder1
     - contents.csv
  abc.csv
  file.xlsx
  .gitignore
  file1.yml
  gfile.geojson
```

When I do `git add .`, all the files and folders are staged. How do I ignore `folders`, and files with `csv` and `xlsx` extensions?

The contents of `.gitignore`: `*.[xls,xlsx,csv]`

I am only trying to commit code in files with ext `.py`, `.ipynb`, `.yml`, and `.geojson`.

Comment: To ignore all folders try `*/`

Answer (score 1):

The range notation `[]` applies only to characters, similar to regex syntax. Instead list your extensions on separate lines, like this:

```
*.xls
*.xlsx
*.cvs
```

If the all files in a folder are excluded, you'll not see any files from that folder being staged. If you want to explicitly ignore a folder, use a trailing slash:

```
folder1/
```

Comment: @PhilipNgan explicitly specify each folder name in `.gitignore` ? how do I exclude all the folders?

Comment: That is right. If you want to explicitly exclude a folder name, yes, put each in the `.gitignore` file. So if you wanted to ignore a folder that you know is called `folder1`, then put it in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore all folders without explicitly specifying each one of them?